# node.js fails on one computer

Tags: node.js

I have a very simple script to test reading URL parameters. The script executes correctly on 2 computers running node, but the third computer running node fails. 
here is the script:

```
var http = require('http');
var URL = require('url');
var host = '127.0.0.1';
var port = 8181;

// Is called when a request comes in
handler = function(req, res) {
    var url_parts = URL.parse(req.url);
            console.log("url_parts = "+url_parts);

    var query = url_parts.query;
        console.log("xxx query = "+query);

    var qArray = parseGetVars(query); 
    var body = {
        "errorCode": "0","errorMessage":"","params" : qArray
    };

    // sets content-type of the responce
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    });

    // terminates the response, and passes back the json as text.
    res.end(JSON.stringify(body));


};


var parseGetVars = function(thisString) {
    var getVars = new Array();
    var qString = thisString;
    console.log("qString = "+qString);
    if(qString!=''){
        var pairs = qString.split(/\&/);
        for (var i in pairs) {
            var nameVal = pairs[i].split(/\=/);
            getVars[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
        } 
    }
    console.log("getVars = "+getVars);

    return getVars;
}



http.createServer(handler).listen(port, host);

console.log('Server running at http://' + host + ':' + port + '/');
```

call the script as follows:
    http://mydomain.com:8181/?d=1&p=2

As I said, this script runs just fine on 2 computers (all running v0.10.7). On the third I get this error in the console:

```
Server running at http://localhost:8181/
url_parts = [object Object]
xxx query = d=1&p=2
qString = d=1&p=2
getVars = 
url_parts = [object Object]
xxx query = null
qString = null

/Users/me/Sites/node/params.js:36
        var pairs = qString.split(/\&/);
                            ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of null
    at parseGetVars (/Users/me/Sites/node/params.js:36:23)
    at Server.handler (/Users/me/Sites/node/params.js:14:15)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2027:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:119:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1917:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:510:27)
```

any ideas greatly appreciated

Comment: `qString != ''` doesn't mean that `qString != null`. Just do `if (qString)`.

Comment: On another sidenote, `!=` is almost never right, you most probably meant `!==`.

Comment: any reason your parsing the querystring yourself? `url.parse` can do it for you

Comment: Your log output for the error is indicating two requests, the second of which is without a query string (likely a favicon.ico request?). Is this the same behaviour on all servers?

Comment: thanks scriptfromscratch. I noticed that, and, no, it's not the same behavior on all servers. the failing one is the only one that is called twice. the other 3 comments seem true and irrelevent.